# Table of contents HTML link

Tags: html

In [wikipedia's table of contents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca-cola#Formula_of_natural_flavorings), by simply putting a hash tag and removing the whitespaces using underscores on the desired content, we can jump to different contents in the same page. Is there a HTML tag to do this? Or must I use Javascript? If so, give me the syntax in jQuery since I'm more comfortable with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fragment identifiers on URIs link to [elements with matching ids](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3).

```
<a href="#foo">section name</a>
```

...

```
<div id="foo">section contents</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would link to named anchors, like so:

```
<a name="top"></a>

<a href="#top">go to top of page</a>
```

But you can use any matching ID really.

Comment: Having to add extra elements like that hasn't been needed since Netscape 4 disappeared off the radar.